# Why does std::cout print 4.9999999 as 5?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I was figuring out the difference between `log(3)` and `log10(3)`, using this code:

```
void testPrecisionError() {
    cout
    << log(243) / log(3) << " : "
    << int(log(243) / log(3)) << " : "
    << endl;

    cout
    << log10(243) / log10(3) << " : "
    << int(log10(243) / log10(3)) << " : ")
    << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
5 : 4  // I think it is 4.999999 underlying
5 : 5
```

I found out that `4.999999` is printed out as `5`.

Why doesn't C++ print it as `4.99999` like Java does?

I guess I could no more `cout` to convince myself that there is NO PRECISON LOSS !

Comment: The default precision is 6.

Comment: Why doesn't C++ print it as 4.99999 like Java??

Comment: 4.99999 has only 5 digits of precision, not 6 like default C

Comment: Java prints "[as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type `double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))", so it prints [`4.999999999999999`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DgyUgit1s2V2tGTR).

Comment: @T.C.[Except when it doesn't](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-doesnt-print-the-shortest-strings-that-round-trip/)

Answer (score 3):

Because it's rounding to the nearest value of the last digit of the requested precision. The actual value is about:

```
4.99999999999999911182158029987
```

And with 6 digits of precision, that's closer to `5.000000` than `4.999999`, so it shows `5`. If you use `setprecision(16)` or higher you'll see all the 9's.

When you cast to `int`, it always truncates, it doesn't round to the nearest value.

As for why Java displays it as `4.999999`, maybe it just discards extra digits rather than rounding.

Comment: Java doesn't display it as 4.999999. It displays it as 4.999999999999999.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of binary where real numbers cannot be represented correctly! `double` and `float` have a precision problem. So you need to be careful when you are comparing 2 `double` values etc...

For example:

- `sqrt(2) = [real value of sqrt(2)] +/- [precision error]`
- precision error depend on the type / cpu architecture you are using (double, float...)

Comment: Why doesn't C++ print it as 4.99999 like Java??

Comment: Java may have an other kind of representation for float/double value, which precision is better than C (use of class etc...)

Comment: Why would C++ do anything like Java?  C++ was created and standardized before Java even existed.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point output in iostreams is controlled by the stream's [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/).  The default IIRC is 6 places to the right of the decimal.  If the 7th digit is a 9, it rounds the 6th digit up, and so on.  In your case, 4.9999999... becomes 5.

Maximum decimal precision in IEEE 754, which is probably what you're using, is around 15 decimal places.  If you set the stream's precision to 16 or so (with the [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) manipulator), you'll see "all" the digits.  But of course it's still only an approximation, because that what floating-point numbers are.

Why isn't it like Java?  Two languages, two sets of rules.  I'd argue that Java is wrong: if the 7th position is 9, then 4.99999 is off by 0.0000009+, whereas 5.0 is off by only 0.0000001+.  Do you want more digits, or a closer approximation?